# Optimizing Copy and Paste from one workbook to another in VBA

Tags: performance, optimization, copy-paste

I have several .xlsm templates in a folder. I'm trying to read through all the excel files in that folder and based on the type of the file, it reads through all the sheets in each file and copy specific cells into another my active workbook (ThisWorkbook).
Following is my code and it is working correctly. However it is super slow. I'm looking for any solution that can speed up the code. I've already tried Application.ScreenUpdating = False but still it is very slow. It takes about 10 min for 20 files to be processed. 
DO you guys have any suggestion on how to increase the speed.
Thanks Veru mich in Advance
...

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileType = "*.xls*"     
    OutputRow = 5   
    Range("$B$6:$M$300").ClearContents
    filepath = Range("$B$3") & "\" 

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & OutputRow).Activate
    OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
    Curr_File = Dir(filepath & FileType)
    Do Until Curr_File = ""
        Set FldrWkbk = Workbooks.Open(filepath & Curr_File, False, True)
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & OutputRow) = Curr_File
        OutputRow = OutputRow

        For Each sht In FldrWkbk.Sheets
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & OutputRow) = sht.Name
            If Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Range("B7") = "Project Number" Then
             For i = 1 To 4
              If IsEmpty(Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Cells(10, 5 + 2 * i)) = False Then
                With Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name)
                   MyE = .Cells(10, 5 + 2 * i).Value
                   MyF = .Cells(11, 5 + 2 * i).Value
                End With
                With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
                  .Range("D" & OutputRow).Value = "Unit Weight"
                  .Range("E" & OutputRow).Value = MyE
                  .Range("F" & OutputRow).Value = MyF
                End With
                OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
              End If
             Next
            OutputRow = OutputRow - 1
            ElseIf Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Range("C6") = "PROJECT NUMBER" Then
             With Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name)
                   MyE = .Range("$H$9").Value
                   MyF = .Range("$B$9").Value

             End With
             With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            .Range("D" & OutputRow).Value = "Specific Gravity"
            .Range("E" & OutputRow).Value = MyE
            .Range("F" & OutputRow).Value = MyF
            End With

            ElseIf Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Range("C6") = "Project Number" Then

            With Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name)
                   MyE = .Range("$E$4").Value
                   MyF = .Range("$R$4").Value
                   MyG = .Range("$R$5").Value
             End With
             With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
             .Range("D" & OutputRow).Value = "Sieve & Hydrometer"
             .Range("E" & OutputRow).Value = MyE
             .Range("F" & OutputRow).Value = MyF
             .Range("G" & OutputRow).Value = MyG
            End With

            ElseIf Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Range("A6") = "PROJECT NUMBER" Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D" & OutputRow).Value = "Moisture Content"

            Last = Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("I" & OutputRow).Value = 
            Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Cells(Last, 10)

            ElseIf Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Range("C5") = "Project Number" Then
            With Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name)
                   MyE = .Range("$H$8").Value
                   MyF = .Range("$B$8").Value
                   MyG = .Range("$D$8").Value
             End With
             With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
             .Range("D" & OutputRow).Value = "Atterberg Limits"
             .Range("E" & OutputRow).Value = MyE
             .Range("F" & OutputRow).Value = MyF
             .Range("G" & OutputRow).Value = MyG
             End With

            ElseIf Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name).Range("B5") = "Project Number" Then
            With Workbooks(Curr_File).Worksheets(sht.Name)
                   MyE = .Range("$G$4").Value
                   MyF = .Range("$E$4").Value
                   MyG = .Range("$E$5").Value
            End With
            With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
             .Range("D" & OutputRow).Value = "Gradation Size"
             .Range("E" & OutputRow).Value = MyE
             .Range("F" & OutputRow).Value = MyF
             .Range("G" & OutputRow).Value = MyG
             End With
            End If
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        Next sht
        FldrWkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Curr_File = Dir
    Loop
    Set FldrWkbk = Nothing
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

...

Comment: How many sheets of how many rows are involved in your setup ?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Depending on the file It is variant from 1 to 20 Work Sheets per Workbook. There are not much to be copied from each sheet. Maximum of 10 separate cells are to be copied from each sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just realized that the slow performance is due to the formulations that are written in the excel but are linked to the ranges that are pasted from the Macro code. As it was addressed in the previous stack overflow solutions, I simply added "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual" in the beginning of the code and "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic" at the end of the code and now it is much much faster.

I hope it is also useful to whom is reading this